# "No Input Detected"?

Tags: windows-7, display

So, I bought a 25in [Hannspree HD Monitor](http://www.hannspree.com/US/product_detail.aspx?id=25670&key=hf259), but it isn't working as intended. To make a long story short, I discovered that if I connect my computer to my old monitor (via VGI-VGA -> VGA), then I am able to see the desktop (or whatever the computer is suppose to be displaying). Then if I just switch the end connection from my old monitor to my new, then it also displays correctly. However, if I go into the settings and click "detect" then everything goes blank again. It also says in the settings that I am connected to my old monitor when I am really connected to my new one. When I turn off the computer then I usually have to do this process over because I am essentially tricking the computer by telling it that it is on my old monitor when it really isn't because the new one is too retarded! Anyone know how I might fix this? I installed the driver from the CD and looked through the manual and searched on the internet, but could not find what I was looking for. Thanks!

(PS I am using a Radeon 6000 series [6950 to be specific] graphics card and running Windows 7)

Oh, and HDMI -> DVI or HDMI -> HDMI does not work at all. I suppose that is my main goal because it is an awful shame not to display in full HD!

Comment: You want to use HDMI so you can display in *full HD*???  Dude, HD is _low_ resolution compared to what DVI and VGA deliver. 1080p is only 1920x1080.  A large monitor like that must be able to deliver something rather higher res than that through DVI...  My 19" does 1680x1050 native...  Ugh - looks like that "monitor" only does 1920x1080 maximum - that would look ghastly close to.  It's just a TV without the tuner...  It'd look fine across the room but I wouldn't want one on my desk...

Comment: Yes, I can only go to 1280 X 1024!!! Games still look pretty good, but I want to crank it ALL THE WAY UP! I did spend my whole life's savings to buy the damn things (computer+monitor). lol